# Is there a way to pass array of hash to provider function in Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I know we can pass boolean, String, Array and Hash kind_of attributes to provider functions.
However is there a way to pass Array of Hash kind_of attribute to provider functions.
What would be the right way to achieve this?

**attributes/default.rb**

```
default['test']['users'] = [
{
    'name'          =>  'haris',
    'age'           =>  '21'
},
{
    'name'          =>  'Omar',
    'age'           =>  '25'
}
]
```

**resources/default.rb**

```
 actions :add, :delete
 attribute :users,      :kind_of => [Array, Hash], :required => true
```

**providers/default.rb**

```
action :add do
users       = @new_resource.users

users.each do |user|
   user <blah blah>
end
```

**recipes/default.rb**

```
cbook_my_users "add users" do
    action :add
    users "#{node['test']['users']}"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than making it a string, just pass through the object itself: `users node['test']['users']`